# Extending ListView class

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I want to have a ListView that in addition to "item.Text" and "item.Name" should have some more custom properties for each ListViewItem.

How can I do that (syntax and etc...)

Also is it possible to set a `List<string>` or `List<class>` as a property of an listview item?

Thanks.

Comment: Avoid using a control as a collection class.  Separate the data from the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inherit from ListViewItem class.

```
public class MyListViewItem : ListViewItem {
    public List<object> Tags {get; set;}
}

// ... elsewhere

var item = new MyListViewItem {
    Text = "Hello world!",
    Tags = new List<object> { null, true, 15, "asdf", 78.7 }
};
this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: also mention how to get item... MyListViewItem myItem = (MyListViewItem)listView1.Items[0];

Comment: hmm, I was thinking of the whole ListView class, not the item only. will this do the same thing? I want all the items have same proprety attributes.

Comment: The ListViewItem is another class than ListView. You can not "add property" to every item in listview. The every item can be instance of different class derived from ListView.